# PHP - Echo Just Text or Divs and Layout?

Tags: php

I've always thought about this and I can't decide what to do. Lets say I have a `<div>` and I want to echo specific links in it if the user is an admin or a just a member.

Would it be best to have the `<div>` in the HTML, and just do some `if` echos within it?

Or should you echo the whole entire div and everything inside it?

There is no possibilty of the div being empty.

Comment: Depends on framework and template engine if you use any, but I'd go with code: `<?php if( ...){echo $this->displayThatLink();}`

Comment: @Vyktor Why do you assume a framework a/o a template engine? Anyway, I'd go with that too, it's more readable and less error-prone

Comment: @DamienPirsy it just seems ineffective to write code in php from scratch when you've got powerful frameworks like YIC, Zend and so on.

Comment: @Vyktor well, yes, agree, but that's not an assumption here; OP might be doing "from scratch", using a custom framework (or building one!), a CMS, a copy/pasted code, whatever, and its question (thought overly broad) would still apply; it has nothing to do with frameworks or anything, just how to mix php and html the "best" way

Comment: Anyway, I see why this kind of subjective questions is not seen well here

Answer (score 0):

You probably should go with code like (for simple application):

```
<div class="nav">
  <a href="/">Index</a>
  <a href="/profile">Profile</a>
<?php
  if( $this->isAdmin()){
    echo $this->getAdminLinks();
  }
?>
</div>
```

Or rather something like this:

```
<?php
  echo $this->getAdminLinks();
?>
```

and let that function care about whether to display or not function. For example [Zend uses inline php](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.scripts.html) in phtml templates *(and I consider Zend great place where to learn)*.

If you're building complex application (multiple styles, complex navigation, many different types of pages and many conditions how to generate menu) or you use MVC framework, you should go with code:

```
<?php
  echo $this->getNavigation();
?>
```

Code like this may get really hard to read (imagine 70 lines like this):

```
<a href="one">One</a>
<?php echo $this->getSecond(); ?>
<a href="third">Third</a>
<?php // some crazy stuff with 2 submenu levels
?>
```

Anyway, there's no one "good way" to do this, it's all based on what you need and how do you like your codes written.

Comment: And the function getAdminLinks would actually be doing all the work ? echoing everything? calling the function just gives u the location?

Comment: I'd write it as: `if( !$this->isAdmin()){return '';} return '<a href...></a>'`